# How do I extrapolate a series using the growth rates in another series in panel data?

Tags: stata

I have a massive (~123 million observations) panel data set with data for several pairs of series, e.g. `amount_old` and `amount_new`. The series `amount_new` extends farther forward in time than the series `amount_old`, so I want to extrapolate the values of `amount_old` using the growth rates calculated from `amount_new`.

Here is a small sample data set:

```
clear

input str3 str_id year amount_old amount_new
       aaa   2000     1105.34      1568.2  
       aaa   2001   1122.6268   1571.8486  
       aaa   2002   1132.0478    1605.832  
       aaa   2003   1186.9295   1666.4644  
       aaa   2004   1187.2502   1714.0043  
       aaa   2005   1230.0004   1744.4136  
       aaa   2006   1252.9979   1821.2219  
       aaa   2007   1289.5164   1855.4785  
       aaa   2008   1351.6705   1864.0597  
       aaa   2009    1353.639   1877.5152  
       aaa   2010   1398.2009   1916.5298  
       aaa   2011           .   1921.5906  
       aaa   2012           .   2003.8804  
       aaa   2013           .   2051.6525  
       aaa   2014           .   2072.8235  
       bbb   2000   7964.3029     9043.68  
       bbb   2001   8062.8454   9319.9098  
       bbb   2002    8223.277   9415.5202  
       bbb   2003   8605.8333    9760.014  
       bbb   2004   8636.8787   10024.964  
       bbb   2005   8927.8641   10327.588  
       bbb   2006     9284.91   10408.275  
       bbb   2007           .   10693.495  
       bbb   2008           .   11141.559  
       bbb   2009           .   11367.394  
       bbb   2010           .   11671.628  
       bbb   2011           .   11994.248  
       ccc   1990    20593.59   31049.493  
       ccc   1991   20723.578   31364.674  
       ccc   1992   21119.377   32870.953  
       ccc   1993           .   33138.507  
       ccc   1994           .   33383.829  
       ccc   1995           .   33776.957  
       ccc   1996           .   33966.004  
       ccc   1997           .   34324.091  
       ccc   1998           .   35744.175  
end
```

Once the data are loaded, I can extrapolate by looping through each observation:

```
encode str_id, gen(id)
xtset id year
gen amount_new_gr = amount_new / L.amount_new - 1
forv i = 1/`=_N' {
    if missing(amount_old[`i']) {
        replace amount_old = amount_old[`=`i'-1'] * (1 + amount_new_gr[`i']) in `i'
    }
}
```

but this is fairly slow and a huge data set, and I'll need to do this for around 45 pairs of series (`series1_old`, `series1_new`, `series2_old`, etc.).

Is there a way to do this in Stata 13 using lag operators or some other characteristic of the panel data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really want to do this (statistically it may not be your best option), try the alternative presented within the code:

```
clear
set more off

*----- exmple data -----

input str3 str_id year amount_old amount_new
       aaa   2000     1105.34      1568.2  
       aaa   2001   1122.6268   1571.8486  
       aaa   2002   1132.0478    1605.832  
       aaa   2003   1186.9295   1666.4644  
       aaa   2004   1187.2502   1714.0043  
       aaa   2005   1230.0004   1744.4136  
       aaa   2006   1252.9979   1821.2219  
       aaa   2007   1289.5164   1855.4785  
       aaa   2008   1351.6705   1864.0597  
       aaa   2009    1353.639   1877.5152  
       aaa   2010   1398.2009   1916.5298  
       aaa   2011           .   1921.5906  
       aaa   2012           .   2003.8804  
       aaa   2013           .   2051.6525  
       aaa   2014           .   2072.8235  
       bbb   2000   7964.3029     9043.68  
       bbb   2001   8062.8454   9319.9098  
       bbb   2002    8223.277   9415.5202  
       bbb   2003   8605.8333    9760.014  
       bbb   2004   8636.8787   10024.964  
       bbb   2005   8927.8641   10327.588  
       bbb   2006     9284.91   10408.275  
       bbb   2007           .   10693.495  
       bbb   2008           .   11141.559  
       bbb   2009           .   11367.394  
       bbb   2010           .   11671.628  
       bbb   2011           .   11994.248  
       ccc   1990    20593.59   31049.493  
       ccc   1991   20723.578   31364.674  
       ccc   1992   21119.377   32870.953  
       ccc   1993           .   33138.507  
       ccc   1994           .   33383.829  
       ccc   1995           .   33776.957  
       ccc   1996           .   33966.004  
       ccc   1997           .   34324.091  
       ccc   1998           .   35744.175  
end

// create more observations
expand 60000

bysort str_id year : gen idpre = _n
egen id = group(idpre str_id)

order id
drop str_id idpre

// xtset the data
xtset id year

// clear timers
timer clear

*----- original -----

timer on 1

gen amount_new_gr = amount_new / L.amount_new - 1

clonevar amount_old2 = amount_old

quietly forv i = 1/`=_N' {
    if missing(amount_old2[`i']) {
        replace amount_old2 = amount_old2[`=`i'-1'] * (1 + amount_new_gr[`i']) in `i'
    }
}

timer off 1

*----- alternative -----

timer on 2

gen growth = amount_new / L.amount_new

clonevar amount_old3 = amount_old

quietly bysort id : replace amount_old3 = L.amount_old3 * growth ///
    if missing(amount_old3)

timer off 2

// results
timer list
```

The `timer` commands allow us to benchmark both versions; your original (1) and the proposed alternative (2). Time is measured in seconds:

```
. timer list
   1:     36.82 /        1 =      36.8180
   2:      0.83 /        1 =       0.8260
```

With this data set of approximately 2 million observations, there is a huge increase in speed when using the alternative.

Additionally, the code is simpler and reads easier. Notice I am using the `if` *qualifier* and not the `if` *command* (see [the difference](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/index.html)). There is no need to loop over observations given that Stata does that for us automatically.

Read also `help by`, a basic and very important construct in Stata.

Comment: Thank you. I knew `by` was the right way to go about this, but I had some mistake in my `by` code that caused it to fail. This is exactly what I was looking for.